# How to debug a Javascript file using Chrome Dev tools which is loaded via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I had to load a javascript file via javascript by creating a script tag and appending it to the document head instead of putting a script tag in my JSP. Due to this the JS file doesn't show up anymore in the Chrome Dev tool sources. All the other files which are loaded as script are visible in the Dev tool sources except this one. Is there a way to debug such files using the Chrome Dev tools?

Comment: As far as I have just checked with Chrome 73, if you attach a `script` element (with external source, through use of its `src` attribute) to your document, it shows up automatically in the Debugger in Developer Tools, no need to do anything. Maybe you can clarify how you actually get the script to execute? Is it an inline script?

Comment: @amn I am dynamically inserting <script type="text/javascript" src="/myscript.js"></script> into the document <head> and when I look for myscript.js in the source, I am not able to find it in Chrome 73 too.

Answer (score 0):

If you refresh the tab with DevTools open you should be able to select your HTML page in the Sources tab. From there you can put breakpoints in inline scripts.

Comment: It is not an inline script, it is a dynamically loaded Javascript file.

Comment: @newbie hmm, what happens if you add `debugger;` to the js file and then refresh with DevTools open? Maybe that will guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript file, which is dynamically loaded via created `<script>` tag, merges with the JS code, which had created this tag. The 'merge' means that all global variables and functions are added/replaced within that JS in run time. You then may debug this resulted code as usual.

Comment: I am inserting <script type="text/javascript" src="/myscript.js"></script> and not the code itself.

Comment: @newbe Yes. The inserted script file (in this case) behaves just like you would insert inline code.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried pressing ctrl + p (or command + p if you are using osx) in dev tools and then looking the file up there!?